# How to evaluate object properties for Mongodb collection within child templates in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am rendering table dynamically.

**Templates are defined as below:**

```
<template name="home">
<div class="row">
    <div class="tblCSV">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>

            // Dynamic Header Row - Working
            <tr>
                {{#each columns}}
                    <th>
                        {{columnName}}
                    </th>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>

            </thead>

            // Dynamic Rows - Working
            <tbody>
            {{#each entries}}
                {{> entry}}
            {{/each}}
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

// if i try to iterate columns to print values per row, it prints field/column name instead it's value
<template name="entry">
    <tr>

        {{#each columns}}
        // columnName is a mongodb field name, Not Working
            <td>{{columnName}}</td>  // This prints text of Column name itself instead its value
        {{/each}}

    </tr>
</template>

// If i use static column names, it prints all the column values perfectly
<template name="entry">
    <tr>
        <td>{{MyColumnName1}}</td> //This prints value of column name i.e. MyColumnValue
        <td>{{MyColumnName2}}</td>
        <td>{{MyColumnName3}}</td>
        <td>{{MyColumnName4}}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

**Template Script**

```
Template.home.helpers({
entries: function () {
    return Entry.find();
},
columns: function () {
    return Column.find();
}
});
Template.entry.helpers({
    columns: function () {
        return Column.find();
    }
});
```

**This is what the problem is**
[image: Problematic Result]

**This is what i want**
[image: Expected Result]

Feel free to ask for any information you need.

Comment: I don't get it. Your code for the columns helper in home is exactly the same as in entry, so why would you expect any different behavior? also, if your home template is working fine, why not use that? I guess it's not entirely clear what the problem is you are trying to solve.

Comment: I am a meteor newbie @ChristianFritz. i got your point on **columns** helper, and i'll definitely refactor it. But that is not the problem. Just look at *entry  template*, it evaluates **columnName** as a text. see first image. What i am trying to do is i want to print the values of columns. see second image. Just see *entry template* with static column names, its just working fine. Do you get it or need any other information !